# My website subdomain redirects to the main domain, how to prevent this?

Tags: redirection, subdomain

I have a website subdomain created, and when in a browser I type the subdomain address, it gets automatically redirected to the main domain. Only when I add index.html to the URL, the subdomain text is shown.

How can I prevent this?

The only file in the subdomain existing was a .htaccess file (which I removed, no change), and index.html (which I filled with some text).

I'm using a Windows computer, the address I want (not to be redirected) is:

```
http://gigs.mkspace.nl
```

The page I want to see when I type the above is:

```
http://gigs.mkspace.nl/index.html
```

The hosting provider is hosting2go.nl (not sure what is uses, I don't think Windows). I use the (free) pages from hosting2go.nl (mainly the filemanager, means changing files manually).

Comment: Check your webserver configuration for errors.

Comment: @Seth where can I find that? (I'm quite a novice regarding building websites)

Comment: That would be up for you to figure out because you have excluded any information about what you're using. Whenever it's a hosted site, a Windows or Linux server, what webserver software you're using and so on.

Comment: @Seth I updated some information, I'm not sure what server it is.

Comment: I see a gigs page when I go to http://gigs.mkspace.nl (without index.html). Are you sure it's not some browser cache issue on your client?

Comment: I don't really see a free tier. So I'm not sure what you're using. If you only file manager to upload file (maybe even through their website) you won't be able to change the webserver configuration directly and will have to check the tools they provide. You might be able to use a htaccess file. Check their help to see what they write about e.g. just having to use a `index.php` rather than HTML file.

Comment: @mtak yes that is it ... not sure how to fix it on my browser (it works correct with internet explorer) ... guess I have to remove history or so. Thanks!

Comment: @Seth Thanks (mtak just checked and it works on another browser, so it's some history issue of my browser).